# Css class not found in Phantomjs

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, phantomjs

Some css classes that are added by javascript if phantomjs  is used as driver css classes are not loaded but when mozilla firefox is used as driver css classes are loaded. Unable to find the issue.

Code Sample
for phantom driver: `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()`
for firefox driver: `driver = webdriver.Firefox()`

```
driver.get("/admin/xyz")
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("percent") 
# [] in case of Phantomjs
# [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="3d414", element="{ce08}")>] in case of firefox
```

Comment: Have you checked that the page been opened successfully at all?

Comment: @Vaviloff I have checked that. And also added time.sleep(60) after driver.get yet css not loading in Phantomjs

Comment: Try to use Firefox's user agent to check if the site does browser sniffing.